# Ajax Url is not reaching the controller via IIS

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

When I run the application in IIS, it stucks in Home controller and doesn't continue to the next controller(Data controller) as I wrote in the URL. When I run this in debug mode, it works, not in IIS. How can I fix it?

```html
     <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('1');
         $(document).ready(setInterval(function () {
             
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/api/data/',
                 
                 data: { pcName: '' },
                 type: 'GET',
                 success: function (CLID) {
                     //
                     
                     if (CLID != null) {

                         $.ajax({

                             data: { line: CLID },
                             type: 'POST',
                             datatype: 'html',
                             url: '/Home/PopPage/',
                             success: function (data) {
                                 var w = window.open("about:blank", 'PopPage', 'height=300,width=200');
                                 $(w.document.body).html(data.toString());
                             }
                         });                        
                     }
                 }
             });

         }, 2000));
         
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you Try using "async: false"..????

Comment: Where should i write it? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Add a param in first ajax call.

Comment: Well, I tried, but it doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the razor syntax for creating URL

```
url : '@Url.Content("~/api/controllername/actionname")'

url : '@Url.Content("~/Home/PopPage")'
```

OR 
`url: '@Url.Action("PopPage", "Home")'`

because, after hosting, you need to consider the Application name given in the iis. This could be an issue